# A question about long dash in a paper about martingales

Tags: probability-theory, notation, martingales

I was reading a paper and saw this notation used for an expected value (first line and second to last line): $E(|X_n| \mbox{---} |X_n| \le K$.

[image: screenshot of the paper]

I'm fairly certain that this isn't just a minus sign, but I'm not sure what exactly it could be. I feel that I missed something obvious.

Comment: The notation $\mathbb E(|X_n|-|X_n|\leq K)$ has no sense, moreover, $|X_n|-|X_n|=0$... Wouldn't it be $\mathbb E(|X_n|\mid |X_n|\leq K)$ ?

Comment: Could you please provide the paper? A good idea is to search for other papers from the same authors. May be they define therein their nomeclature. I think there are some misprints in the provided equation however. Is that a screen shot from the paper or is that you that you have type in the equation?

Comment: It's a screenshot from the paper, yes - I was thinking that it could simply be a misprint too, since Surb's suggestion makes much more sense. Thanks for the help - I wasn't sure if its a paper's mistake or if its something I don't know.

Comment: My guess is that $E(X — Y\in A)$ is simply $E(X \mathbf{1}_{\{Y\in A\}})$. A more standard notation is $E(X; Y\in A)$.